# Web-browser is not showing the output

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and already encountered a problem. When I run the code and the browser pops up, it[browser] does not show anything. What I have is the `testMethod.js` file with one method:

```
function testMethod(num1, num2){
    var value = num1 + num2;
    return value;
}
```

and an `HTML` file from where I'm trying to run:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> My JavaScript</title>
    <script language = "javascript" src = testMethod.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script language = "javascript" type = "text/javascript">

    // var getValue = testMethod(2,3);
      document.write("The result is " + testMethod(5,3));


  </script>
  <noscript>
      <h3> This site requires JavaScript</h3>
  </noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

The code is not implementing the result at all. It shows only a blank page browser.

Comment: Any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: Check your <script> statement you are missing the opening quotes :p

Comment: `<script language = "javascript" src = testMethod.js"></script>`

Comment: The deeper cause behind this is you are using something like Notepad, with no code highlighting. The moment I pasted your code into Sublime text, I noticed something was amiss because half the code was yellow, indicating it was part of a string.

Comment: Here is your code in all its glory :p http://imgur.com/WX2dPPf

Comment: Just a note but you can drop the `language="javascript"` part, as it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @RishavKundu, I've been using `phpStorm` but do you think `sublime` is better than `phpStorm`?

Comment: @John here is a picture of your code when I pasted it into sublime http://imgur.com/ItdOgYk There is no doubt that something is wrong syntactically.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a quote missing in the html, it should say `src="testMethod.js"` where you are including the script in the first place.

Comment: If you _are_ going to make my comment into an answer, at least give me some credit.

Comment: @RishavKundu I think it was simultaneous, I didn't see your comment. However, is a very beginner mistake, more than one person can answer the same, is not that rare, and I didn't "stole" your answer :(